# Smarty syntax for turning a dictionary into a string and push it into the data layer

Tags: dictionary, smarty, url-encoding, smarty3

I am trying to find a way to pass a string variable (coming from a dictionary) into my website's data layer.

My array is built using the following snippet:

```
     [{foreach from=$orderArticles item="currOrderArticle"}]
         [{assign var="currBasePrice2" value=$currOrderArticle-getBasePrice()}]
         product_list.push(
                           { 
                           id: "[{$currOrderArticle-oxorderarticles__oxartnum->value}]", 
                           price: [{$currBasePrice2->getBruttoPrice()}], 
                           quantity: [{$currOrderArticle-oxorderarticles__oxamount->value}] 
                           }
         );
         products_info.push(
                           {
                           transaction_id: '[{$order->oxorder__oxordernr-value}]', 
                           transaction_cid: '[{$order->oxorder__oxuserid-value}]', 
                           item_id: '[{$currOrderArticle-oxorderarticles__oxartnum->value}]',
                           item_value: '[{$basket-getDiscountedNettoPrice()}]',
                           item_quantity: '[{$currOrderArticle-oxorderarticles__oxamount->value}]'
                           }
         );
     [{/foreach}]
```

If I want to pass it to the data layer, I do the following:

```
dataLayer.push({
    ProductsInfo: products_info
```

});

This works fine, the issue is that I actually want to modify this array.
I would like to apply the following to it before passing it into the data layer:

```
products_info|json_encode|escape:'url'
```

But when I try to do it during the push, it does not work:

```
   dataLayer.push({
        ProductsInfo: products_info|json_encode|escape:'url'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you in another post, Smarty expressions must be enclosed in delimiters, in your case [{ and }]

Also, as you're using the string in javascript, it must be enclosed within quotes:

```
 dataLayer.push({
        ProductsInfo: '[{products_info|json_encode|escape:'url'}]'
});
```